# InputType Suggest IOS

Tags: genexus, smartdevice

Tenho um edit com Input Type Descriptions. Ao fazer uma pesquisa em um IOS, só me permite digitar 8 caracteres.

Alguém já teve esse problema? Será que é um bug?

[image: Print da propriedades]

Comment: Temos um problema com o "suggest", o comprimento do atributo é o máximo que pode escrever. Deve ser o comprimento da descrição. Vamos corrigir.

Comment: O tamanho do atributo em questão (ProdutoDescricao) é de 120 caracteres.